# WebBrowser control won't print from C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I've got a WebBrowser control on a WinForms app that is loading XML which is converted to HTML/CSS. Looks beautiful if I just want to view it there or in a regular browser.

When the form loads, it's supposed to navigate to the file, then when the OnDocumentCompleted event fires, it should set the header, footer, and default printer name in the registry, then call Print() for however many copies the user has specified.

I've run it through the debugger, and it's calling webBrowser.Print() the correct number of times in the OnDocumentCompleted event. Nothing is null that shouldn't be, Visible is true on the WebBrowser control, as is AllowNavigation. And yes, the printer is turned on and reachable over the network. The exact same code works elsewhere in the project, but not here.

What else could be causing this hellish control to ignore my Print commands?

Ideally, I'd like the whole thing to be hidden off-screen, as this is meant to run using Windows Scheduler, and the users should never see it. I've read that the control needs to be visible, though, so until I work out this first kink, that can wait.

**EDIT**: The last two lines of my OnDocumentCompleted event handler set the DialogResult to OK and closed the form. Removing the call to Close() let it print, so I'm guessing it didn't get to the print spooler before the form was closed and the WebBrowser control was disposed.

Short of just setting an arbitrary time limit to wait before closing, is there any way to tell when it is done printing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out to be a timing issue, with the form being closed before it could send the document to the print spooler. I wound up adding a Timer to the form, setting it for 30 seconds, and having it's Tick() event close the form. Where it was closing the form previously, it now just calls closeTimer.Start().

Comment: This depends on how long the job gets to spooler, which assumes you don't need to handle large jobs and print system availability is high. If you have to go this way, you could just put a thread sleep for 30 and then close form. It is better to have a higher level control based on status of print job to guarantee the job gets printed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc;
doc = oWeb.Document;        
doc.execCommand("Print", True, Nothing);
```

**FROM EDIT:**

It is possible to use SHELL commands to check the status of the jobs in the print queue

Comment: Can't convert webBrowser.Document (HTMLDocument) to any of the IHTMLDocument* interfaces. HTMLDocument does have it's own ExecCommand, which I called using your suggestion. Whether I set showUI to true or false, nothing happens.

Comment: you may have to explicitly tell it to convert the Document object to an IHTMLDocument2 object using "(IHTMLDocument2)oWeb.Document;" Also, ensure that you have the MSHTML dll as a reference in your project.

Regardless, this is how I'm printing the contents of the browser control.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way i fount to print an HTML from a string

```
void PrintString(string strHTMLText)
{
    WebBrowser wbPrintString = new WebBrowser() { DocumentText = string.Empty };
    wbPrintString.Document.Write(strHTMLText);
    wbPrintString.Document.Title = "Type The Header You Want Here";
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rgkySetting = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\PageSetup", true);
    rgkySetting.SetValue("footer", "Type THe Footer You Want Here");
    rgkySetting.Close();
    wbPrintString.Parent = this;
    wbPrintString.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
    wbPrintString.Dispose();
```

}