# How to print a Word document from C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing, ms-word

How can I launch the print of a document from C# .NET application ?
the Word document already exists in the hard drive. I just wish to start printing that Word document upon the button click event.

Comment: More information please, are you generating the document and you wish to print it? Or is it like, your program knows about a Word Document on the computer, and you wish to print that file?

Answer (score 9):

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(wordFilename)
 {
    UseShellExecute = true,
    Verb = "print",
    RedirectStandardOutput = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
 };

 using (Process p = new Process {StartInfo = psi})
 {
     p.Start();
     p.WaitForExit();
 }
```

Comment: You need to add `p.WaitForExit()` (I think), but otherwise this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @Noldorin: Thanks. That would've solved my problem with it closing the form before printing on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878878/webbrowser-control-wont-print-from-c

Comment: Ah, well I'm glad I've answered another question at least. :)

Answer (score 2):

To do this kind of thing you need to know about System.Diagnostics.Process , the MSDN page shows how to pridnt a Word document as an example. A short version:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process printProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 printProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"X:\test\print this.doc";
 printProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
 printProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 printProcess.Start();
```